# How to detect localization on basis of Settings.bundle selection (Story board app)

Tags: localization, storyboard

I am working on an iOS app which is having combination of story board and Localization (based on two languages, i.e. English and Slovenian).

I have created the two folder (en.lproj and sl.lproj) for both the languages. Both are having InfoPlist.string and MainStoryboard.storyboard files. I also need to implement language selection through Settings.bundle.

I have created Settings.bundle and able to select language from my app settings inside device setting option.

Now my trouble points are :

1. How can I get the selected value on AppliactionDidBecomeActive which is being recently set by user from setting?
2. After getting this value, how can I load selected language folder (say en.lproj etc)
3. How can I get the Slovenian language option in device language settings?

My application will work on either by selecting device language or on selecting my NSBundle setting.

Please provide me suggestion on the basis of some code part or help me on any other way.

Thank you and waiting for good response.

Answer (score 0):

1.

> ```
> NSString * lan = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
>
> NSLog(@"language :%@",lan);
> ```

1. Not sure I understand your question (should be automatic).
2. If Slovenian is not yet supported by iOs, there is no way you'll see in the language settings.

In short you'll probably need to add a language selection option in your app. and change the language manually (including for the storyboard) using the NSLocalizedStringFromTable function.

Hope this help